# Explicit Binding UpdateSource() Doesn't Work Until Mouse Hovers Over TextBox

Tags: wpf, binding

So I'm calling the UpdateSource() method on Text property of TextBox in code behind. The ErrorTemplate should come up, but it doesn't until I move my mouse over the TextBox.

Or maybe it does but doesn't get repainted? Any ideas how to fix this to update GUI instantly?

EDIT:

It is PropertyChanged. The problem is not with updating source. The problem is that when source updates, it causes validation and the ErrorTemplate should come up, but it doesn't until I move my mouse over validated TextBox.

EDIT:

Appearently it does update when I move my mouse over some other GUI elements as well (like radio button), which doesn't have anything to do with validation. This is definitely an issue of repainting or binding validation error check trigger. How can I trigger that in code behind?

Comment: Does the textbox go red before the mouseover?  That is the default behavior of the ErrorTemplate.  You might be able to get the behavior you want with a ControlTemplate.

Comment: No it doesn't. ErrorTemplate triggers only on mouse over. That's the problem. However it works fine in all other situations.

Comment: Does the Source implement iNotifyPropertyChanged?   Trace the Get and see when it is called.  You may need to manually throw the error.

Comment: Yes it does, that's not the issue. The error is being thrown at Set. UpdateSource() does update it with an invalid value and an exception is thrown, which should open ErrorTemplate. However, it opens ErrorTemplate only when I hover my mouse on some GUI element. Hovering mouse doesn't hit a breakpoint in either Get or Set.

Comment: Sorry I was not of more help.  See my last guess posted as an answer just for room.  Not like I am telling you anything you have not already figured out but that ErrorTemplate event seems to be called by the TextBox when it has focus and it checks for errors.  Do you have ValidatesOnExceptions=True and NotifyOnValidationError=True ?

Comment: These properties are not the case either.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You may be able to get Validation_Error to fire.

```
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" x:Name="fieldValue" BorderBrush="SteelBlue" BorderThickness="2" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
             Text="{Binding Path=DF.FieldValue, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"
             Validation.Error="Validataion_Error"
             LostFocus="fieldValue_LostFocus"  KeyUp="fieldValue_KeyUp"/>


    private void Validataion_Error(object sender, ValidationErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Action == ValidationErrorEventAction.Added)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Error.ErrorContent.ToString(), "Fatal Update Error");
        }
    }
```

It may be that since that event is on the TextBox is only fires when the TextBox has focus.  You may need to throw a custom event and handle it at the Page/Window.

Comment: Now this is weird. When I make it throw a message box, it updates the GUI. Same effect as if I hover on any WPF element. I guess I'll need to use some ugly hack here. Any ideas what would work?

Comment: Instead of a MessageBox try setting focus on the TextBox.

Comment: In my specific scenario I can't focus it (focus causes a side effect). Any other ideas?

Comment: Well thanks for your help, but this is not really what I'm looking for. I'm sure that there is a way to force the same behavior as message box does. Revalidate or something like that.

Comment: Problem solved. This helped me: http://immortalratblog.blogspot.com/2008/04/weird-solutions-ho-can-i-force-wpf.html

Answer (score 0):

Binding to Text property of 'TextBox' control is quite specific. UpdateSourceTrigger is set to "LostFocus" by default. It is for improving performance. Try to change it to PropertyChanged.

Comment: Sorry for not explaining clearly enough. Please check the updated question.